# Why does my domain redirect in some browsers and not others?

Tags: domains, redirects, dns, cloudflare, a-record

I use three domains and two of them redirect to the third. Let's say they are `A.org`, `B.org`, and `C.org`. Last weekend, I changed the redirects from `{A.org, B.org} -> C.org` to `{A.org, C.org} -> B.org`.

The redirects for domain `A.org` are unchanged and the domain has these settings on Cloudflare: two A records that redirect `A.org` and `www` to 192.0.2.1, proxied by Cloudflare, and a Page Rule that redirects `*A.org/*` to `https://B.org/$2`. The redirects for domain `C.org` now has these same settings.

[image: DNS records]

[image: Page rules]

The issue is that the `www` routes, `https://www.C.org` and `http://www.C.org`, show "Server Not Found" on Firefox and Safari. And yet, the `www` routes redirect to `B.org` on Brave browser, and the non-`www` routes (`https://C.org` and `http://C.org`) also redirect to `B.org` on Firefox and Safari.

For reference, A = atletismoemocional, B = emocoes, C = ginja .

How do I diagnose and fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One day after posting the question, and four days after making the change in domain redirects,  I tried the link again today on Firefox and Safari and it worked. So it may have been simply a question of time for Cloudflare to update or for the browsers to clear the cache.

The reason, as in the comment below: "Browsers aggressively cache permanent redirects. Always clear the browser cache when testing them."

Comment: Browser's aggressively cache permanent redirects. I always suggest clearing the browser cache when testing them.